# Handle creation of root password prompt with ansible

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

How do I handle Ubuntu's request to change the root user's password when initializing a new server?

Currently, I'm just logging in to change the password, and then running the Ansible script, but obviously that defeats the purpose of automation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Set root user's password
  user: name=root password={{ encrypted_root_password }} update_password=always
```

See also [How do I generate crypted passwords for the user module](http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module).

Comment: I'm talking about a new server requesting the user to create a new password for root on the first login.  Ansible is connecting as root and being prompted to create a password.